# CSV Editor needed for large files

Tags: macos, csv, ftp, merge

I am looking for a MAC program to compare, edit, merge, save and export large CSV Databases.

I would like it to have the ability to

- pull data from multiple ftp servers so I don't always have to download and import it manually because I need to do this on a daily basis to check product stocks.
- Compare CSV files for changes to find new products available from suppliers, new prices and quantity changes
- open and save CSV data in semicolon utf-8 german format
- I also need this to be a responsive program, Openoffice is too slow Excel can't handle the file formats I work with plus it is also too slow and numbers I'm not even going to try...

I have a Maxed out 15" Macbook Pro Retina so I know these problems are not my computer...

Any Ideas for a different program to try?

Answer (score 0):

Python has an alright CSV library https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html that I've used before.

Checkout urllib2 for handling ftp https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html more particularly the FTP handler objects

Shouldn't hang up to much. No need for a gui and you should be able to schedule a task in the background.